# Order of Abelianization

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G = G_1 * G_2$ where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are both cyclic of degree $n$ and $m$, and we know that $G/[G, G]$ (i.e., the abelianization of $G$) is isomorphic to $(G_1 / [G_1, G_1]) \oplus (G_2 / [G_2, G_2])$, then how can one conclude $G/[G, G]$ has order $nm$?  Isn't this only the case when $n$ and $m$ are coprime?

Comment: wouldn't $G=G_1*G_2$ be abelian?  meaning $[G,G]=e$?

Comment: Can't you use universal properties to show that the abelianization of a free product is a direct product?

Comment: @JorgeFernández, the OP is referring to the **free product** of groups which is generally not abelian.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product

Comment: $[G_1,G_1]=\{1\}$, because $G_1$ is abelian.

Comment: We never assume $G_1$ or $G_2$ are abelian.  In general, $G = G_1 \oplus G_2$ does not have $nm$ order; consider $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_4$.  This has order 4.

Comment: doesn't cyclic imply abelian?

Comment: Ok yes you're right.  But it still stands that $G = G_1 \oplus G_2$ does not imply $G$ is of order $mn$ even though $G_1$ and $G_2$ are abelian...does it?

Comment: Could someone please help here?

Comment: where did you read this stuff, I might be able to answer in a couple of days but I need to read about that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

The order of a direct sum (in the abelian case) of groups, or of a direct product (non-abelian case) is always the order of the respective cartesian product.

In your case we have

$$G_i/G_i'=G_i/1\cong G_i\implies \left|G/G_1\right|=|G_1|=m\,,\,\,\text{and likewise}\;\;\left|G_2/G_2'\right|=|G_2|=n$$

so the order of their direct sum is the product $\;mn\;$ .

You are perhaps confusing this with the fact that for cyclic finite groups $\;C_m\,,\,\,C_n\;$ of resp. order $\;m,n\;$ ,  we have that

$$C_m\times C_n\cong C_{mn}\iff \text{g.c.d.}\,(m,n)=1$$

Still, the direct product (or sum) has order $\;mn\;$ .

Resuming: in any case, $\;\left|G_1*G_2/(G_1*G_2)'\right|=mn\;$ , and it is **cyclic** iff$\;$ g.c.d$(m,n)=1\;$

Comment: Why $|G'|=1$??? @Timbuc